# How to put report expressions inside double quotes c#

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

I am having a ReportExpression and I need to put them inside double quotes.

```
ReportExpression repex = new ReportExpression();
repex = new ReportExpression("=" + str,  EvaluationMode.Auto);
```

How can I add double quotes to `repex` output value?

I tried the below one and it didn't work.

```
repex = new ReportExpression("\"" + "=" + str,  EvaluationMode.Auto + "\"");
```

Comment: Regular expression or report expression? SSRS expressions aren't regular expressions. Double quotes?  Exactly like any other character (if compile time literal then escape them). That's all. Your attempt has unmatched quote. Are you sure you want to also include = character?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Report Expression. It was typo.

Comment: I supposed, see the second part of the comment. You may want to include expression in your post (is it a formula? A literal string?)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - It is a string.

Comment: Have you tried 2 double quotes without the escape character? `new ReportExpression(""""...`